# How can solve this problem? Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run: arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

Updated context:

When I tried to run flutter project, but I got the this error
`Error: To set up CocoaPods for ARM macOS, run: arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi`

I'd run `arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi`, but still had same issues.

this is information

```
yomate@Mac-mini yomate % sudo gem install ffi
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/rbconfig.rb:230: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/yomate/FlutterDev/flutter/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.15.5
Parsing documentation for ffi-1.15.5
Done installing documentation for ffi after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

How can solve this problem? arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable , environment: Mini M1

When I want to use this commend

`sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi` and `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install cocoapods`

I had got this error. `arch: posix_spawnp: gem: Bad CPU type in executable`

And my flutter still had error.

```
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale
    en-AU)
    ✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
      See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the fix but try uninstalling the ffi gem and installing it again, this time natively: `sudo gem install --user-install ffi`, then just `flutter run`

Comment: Having the same error, and @eeqk suggestion didn't fix it. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: @ConleeC make sure your binaries as well as env architectures are aligned, execute `arch`, `flutter doctor` and `dart --version` - they should all return `darwin-arm` or `arm64`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try with this
`sudo gem uninstall ffi && sudo gem install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc`
[source](https://try%20with%20this%5C%20%60sudo%20gem%20uninstall%20ffi%20&&%20sudo%20gem%20install%20ffi%20--%20--enable-libffi-alloc%60%5C%20%5Bsource%5D%5B1%5D%20%5B1%5D:%20https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same message on a fresh install of macOS 12.4 on a M1 MBA,

```
Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information
```

Turns out Rosetta wasn't installed yet (I'm guessing the transition to Apple Silicon is almost complete then? haha), and once I installed it the warning went away.

Comment: What method did you use to install Rosetta?

Comment: I don't remember either by installing an Intel architecture app or through the command line.